# Can't get output of a function to display using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing an equation solver and have the basic set up working. The user types in the equation they want to solve and the values they have, it then returns an answer. It works fine in the terminal but I cannot get the answer to display in a label.

This is the code I have, I have left out some parts of the GUI and the other equation options.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def runprogramme():
    if e3.get() == "Moment":
        a = float(e1.get())
        b = float(e2.get())
        c = a * b
        answer = print("The Moment is: ", c, "Nm")
        Result = Label(root, c.get()).grid(row = 12, column = 0)
```

I get en error code saying:

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get'

I am not quite sure how to fix this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is `e1`? Looks like you are over writing it with `float` somewhere. Post more code please.

Comment: Based on the code, you appear to be assuming both `e1` and `e2` are either an `Entry` widget or a `StringVar`, but the error is telling you that one or both are floats. Since you didn't provide a working [mcve] we can't say much more about it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your error are on this line, (next time publish all traceback please)

```
Result = Label(root, c.get()).grid(row = 12, column = 0)
```

The c variable are float because you multiply float by float and float variable type have not method get.
Replace this line by :

```
Result = Label(root, c).grid(row = 12, column = 0)
```

Comment: You will need to assign `c` to the `text` parameter, like `text=c`. Your current code will produce an error.

Comment: Hi both, it works now with:

Result = Label(root, text = c).grid(row = 12, column = 0)

Many thanks

Comment: @Choronzon9 Also, just for your information, the variable `Result` will hold `None`, since that is the returned value by all the geometry managers. You will not be able to make any changes to the label later in your code, you can use the gird statement in a separate line so that `Result` continues to hold the instance of the `Label`.